# Does pyspark DataFrame.randomSplit() return a stable split?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am working on a problem with a smallish dataset.  Overtime new data is collected and I would like to add this new data to my dataset.  I have made a unique identifier in my current dataset and I have used `randomSplit` to split this into a train and test set:

```
train, test = unique_lifetimes_spark_df.select("lifetime_id").distinct().randomSplit(weights=[0.8, 0.2], seed=42)
```

If I now update my dataset and re-run the split, will it produce a stable split only expanding the existing groups or do I run the risk of "polluting" my groups?

As an example consider the dataset `[A, B, C, D, E]`. `randomSplit` splits this into two groups:

group 1: `[A, B, C, D]`

group 2: `[E]`

At some point I get an updated dataset `[A, B, C, D, E, F, G]` which I would like to incorporate into my modelling process. By using `randomSplit`, am I **guaranteed** that the returned split would never have `[A, B, C, D]` which originally appeared in group 1 in group 2 and vice versa `[E]` will never appear in group 1 as it originally appeared in group 2?

So the updated split should randomly decide where to put `[F, G]` and the rest should stay in their previously assigned groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you do not have the guarantee that if the original dataset grows, the split will remain the same for the pre existing elements.

You can test it yourself:

```scala
scala> spark.range(5).randomSplit(Array(0.8, 0.2), seed=42).foreach(_.show)
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  1|
|  2|
+---+

+---+
| id|
+---+
|  0|
|  3|
|  4|
+---+


scala> spark.range(6).randomSplit(Array(0.8, 0.2), seed=42).foreach(_.show)
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  0|
|  1|
|  2|
|  3|
|  4|
+---+

+---+
| id|
+---+
|  5|
+---+
```